# New React hook for callbacks

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-hooks

I've been using React for a couple years, with functional components and hooks.  The most frustrating thing I've found has to do with passing callbacks.  I have two concerns:

1. If an element receives a callback from a parent it can't really use that function in a event listener or onEvent field or in a setTimeout/setInterval, because the passed function may be redefined any time the parent rerenders.
2. A function that's generated at each render (like an arrow function) and passed to a child element breaks React.memo().

I've seen some limited solutions to this, such as [useEventListener()](https://usehooks.com/useEventListener/) but not one that addresses all the situations that concern me.

So I've written my own hook that I've called useHandler.  Unlike useCallback, which generates a new function whenever the inputs change, useHandler always returns the same function.  This way the function case be passed to an element using React.memo() or to a setInterval or whatever.

It call be used by the parent element (needed for the React.memo case) or by the child element (if you're worried that a passed-in function might change).  Here's an example of it used in the parent:

```
const onClick = useHandler(event => {
  //Do whatever you want.  Reference useState variables or other values that might change,
})

<MyElement onClick={onClick} />
```

MyElement now always gets the same function, but calling that function will execute the most recent code in the parent element.

Here's an example in the child element:

```
const reportBack = useHandler(props.reportBack)

useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(reportBack, 1000)
}, [reportBack])
```

The interval callback will always call the current reportBack passed from the parent.

The only thing missing for me is that I haven't modified the React eslint config to recognize that that results of useHandler cannot change and thus shouldn't generate a warning if omitted from the dependency list in useEffect or similar.

And finally, here's the source for my onHandler hook:

```
export function useHandler(callback) {
  const callbackRef = useRef()
  callbackRef.current = callback
  return useRef((...args) => callbackRef.current(...args)).current
}
```

My questions are:  Are there any flaws in this solution?  Is it a good way to address my issues with React callbacks?  I haven't found anything more elegant but I'm plenty willing to believe that I've missed something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the second point as I've not used React.memo but the first point is why we have cleanup functions.

Let's say you have a function that is passed as a prop down to your component and you want to use it as an event listener.

If you are attaching this listener inside a useEffect like: `window.addEventListener('someEvent', (event) => someFunctionPassedAsProp(event))`
Then the useEffect can look something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handler = (event) => someFunctionPassedAsProp(event)
  window.addEventListener('someEvent', handler)
  return () => window.removeEventListener('someEvent', handler)
}, [someFunctionPassedAsProp])
```

Similarly for intervals you can do something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => someFunctionPassedAsProp(), 1000)
  return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, [someFunctionPassedAsProp])
```